# python sending json file through a subprocess pipe

Tags: python, json

i want to send a json file through a pipe. so basically this is what im doing

module1.py - this script is where i actually create the json file

```
import urllib, json, subprocess

def get_wip_info(query_str) :

    try :
        temp = urllib.urlopen(query_str).read()
    except :
        time.sleep(2)
        try :
            temp = urllib.urlopen(query_str).read()
        except :
            temp = "ERROR"
    return temp

def Get_Other_INFO() :

    fail_message = None

    serial_number = "xxxx"
    ret_str = get_wip_info("http://servername/TesterURL/api/serial/%s/" %serial_number)

    if "ERROR" not in ret_str :

        ret_json = json.loads(ret_str)

        return ret_json

A = Get_Other_INFO()
ret_json = A

cmd = "python module2.py %s"%dict(ret_json)
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
result = p.stdout.read()

print result
```

so basically if you see, this script is calling for a function in another script called module2.py. in this script, it just parses the json file as below :

```
def okok(ret_json) :

    part_number = str(ret_json.get("product", {}).get("SKU", "ERROR"))
    return part_number

def main():

    A = okok(sys.argv[1])
    print A

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

for some reason i dont get the "part number" printed. is there anything im doing wrong?

i have confirmed that the attribute product.get SKU is not empty. please advise

Comment: You should use [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). it'll wait for it to finish. is there any reason why you can't use the second script as a module (via `import`)?

Comment: hi thank you for replying! noted on the "communicate". however, that doesnt resolve the issue im having. also, i choose to make these scripts executable for performance purposes. any other suggestion please?

Comment: From the python documentation
Warning Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Comment: How did you use it ? can you update the post to reflect those changes? also, i don't think that you are getting any performance advantage by calling the second script like that.

Comment: Hi, i have edited the post to add the subprocess communicate function. im actually having a dll imported into this program and it uses up the memory space alot and at some point it causes lots of instability. this method is proven for good performance and most minimal usage of the os memory.

Comment: thanks for the responses...i decided to use pickle instead... works fine and easier